# Nodejs переменные из txt

Tags: node.js

Есть код на nodejs

```js
/*
* IMPORTS: Libraries that steam-yellow uses.
*/
const SteamUser = require('steam-user');
const readline = require('readline');
const client = new SteamUser();

// NodeJS Readline
const rl = readline.createInterface({
 input: process.stdin,
 output: process.stdout
});

// Overwrite the SteamUser library's persona flags to make it yellow
SteamUser.prototype.setPersona = function (state, name) {
 this._send(SteamUser.EMsg.ClientChangeStatus, {
  "persona_state": state,
  "persona_state_flags": 3847, // This makes it yellow
  "player_name": name
 });
};
// Verbosing info to user
console.log("Welcome to yellow-steam!");
console.log("Join our discord and steam group!");
console.log("WEBSITE: https://drakewitt.github.io/steam-yellow/");

// Prompt for username
rl.question('Username? ', (answer) => {

 let username = answer;
 rl.question('Password? ', (answer) => {
  let password = answer;
  const logOnOptions = {
   accountName: username,
   password: password
  };

  client.logOn(logOnOptions);

  rl.close();
 });
});

client.on('loggedOn', () => {
 client.setPersona(SteamUser.Steam.EPersonaState.Online);
 console.log("Logged In! Press CTRL and C to stop.");
});
```

Нужно что бы программа не спрашивала username и password, а брала их из файлов login.txt и pass.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меняй

```
const logOnOptions = {
            accountName: username,
            password: password
        };
```

и вместо username, password вписывай свои
Как пример можно новый добавить:

```
 const logOnOptionsnew = {
                accountName: usernew,
                password: passwordnew
            };
```

И изменить `client.logOn(logOnOptions,logOnOptionsnew);`
У меня работает ^^